# jQuery countdown in several fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown, jquery-countdown

I'm just a HTML/CSS specialist by trade. And my knowledge of JavaScript/jQuery is not sufficient.

I just can't seem to wrap my head around it and make it work, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the link to what I've done so far... http://www.mhoefman.nl/tmstimer/

The red reset button should reset all the timers to their original times.
The alarm button should be preferably only enabled when the active timer is less than zero.
The timer text should be red as soon as the value is less than zero and the time should add up so I could see how much the penalty time is.
Pressing any button will pause the countdown in the active field. Pressing it again will start the countdown in the field near it from the value it was on.

I have tried to use jQuery.timer.js... but I don't see how I can time all fields independently.

Thanks a million in advance for even trying to help me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, it's really good for multiple timers and very extensible - [link](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).